# Performing arithmetic in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm working on a script that awards "trophies" to the top 4 performers of a game. The table logs each "grab" attempt, the user that performed it, and whether it was successful. I'd like to create a script that is able to pull the top four off of percentage of successful grabs (attempts / successes)

Is something like this possible within the query itself using mysqli?

I have successfully accomplished the code already by just looping through each table entry, but with thousands of attempts per month it just seems like a clunky way to go about it.

Here is an example of a row in the table, I am attempting to grab the top four based off of `monthlyTries`/`monthlySuccessful`

```
 id  userId   PetId   PalId  tries  successfulGrabs monthlyTries   MonthlySuccessful
 5   44550    84564   3967    825      268             120               37
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with a sample of the data please?

Comment: @doublesidedstickytape Added!

Comment: Thanks Miranda - FuzzyTree has sorted it for you though I believe :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a `success` column that's either `1` or `0` you can `sum` the success and divide that by `count(*)` which is the total # of attempts

```
select user_id, sum(success)/count(*) percentage
from attempts a
group by user_id
order by percentage desc
limit 4
```

If the `success` column is not a 1/0 value you can use conditional aggregation

```
select user_id, sum(case when success = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as percentage
from attempts a
group by user_id
order by percentage desc
limit 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can simplify the logic.  If `success` takes on the values 0 and 1:

```
select a.user_id, avg(success) as percentage
from attempts a
group by a.user_id
order by percentage desc
limit 4;
```

Otherwise:

```
select a.user_id, avg(success = 'yes') as percentage
from attempts a
group by a.user_id
order by percentage desc
limit 4;
```